# Указание кодировки в батнике

Tags: windows, cmd

Надо в батнике написать команду для закрытия окна по его заголовку. Начал пробовать для блокнота. Написал такой батник:

```
chcp 1251
taskkill /f /fi "windowtitle eq Безымянный — Блокнот" | find "notepad"
```

работает отлично! Начал писать для нужной прогры. А там в случае открытия ее с ошибкой выплывают одно за другим 2 окна: первое с заголовком, включающим русские буквы, а второе с заголовком чисто из английских букав). Так вот. Мой батник второе-то окно закрывает, а при попытке закрытия первого окна пишет: "Информация: Задачи, отвечающие заданным критериям, отсутствуют." Очевидно, проблема в кодировке окна строки. Попробовал поменять, как еще знаю:

```
chcp 65001
```

не помогло. Не менять тоже пробовал: вообще ерунда выходит: ищет окно с крякозабрами. Значит, нужно перебирать все кодировки с кириллицей, благо, их немного. А где прочитать, как в бат указывать все такие кодировки? Вот, к примеру, нужно установить кодировку ISO 8859-5. Как написать в батнике?

Comment: Может стоит посмотреть в сторону пошика? Там объекты и проблем быть не должно.

Comment: так может не заморачиваться и прибивать в том числе дочерние процессы? Например, **taskkill /f /t**

Comment: Daemon-5, наверное, не пойдет: Я так понял, вы предлагаете закрывать все окна программы? Если так, то не подойдет: могут быть и окна используемой программы, которые закрывать не нужно. don Rumata, это что, дополнительная программа? Гугл на этот запрос выдает всякую фигню. А, вообще, непонятно: задал, вроде, пустяковый вопрос: "Как в батнике называть кодировку?", а внятного ответа не получил. Неужели из-за такой ерунды нужно забивать чем-то комп?

Comment: Я полагаю, под "пошиком" подразумевается PowerShell, который уже есть в системе.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотреть названия, кодовые страницы и энумерацию всех доступных кодировок можно так:

```
powershell /nop /ex bypass "&{[Text.Encoding]::GetEncodings()}"
```

или в файл codepages.txt:

```
powershell /nop /ex bypass "&{[Text.Encoding]::GetEncodings()}" > codepages.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

Взято с [сайта MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

```
037 IBM037  IBM EBCDIC US-Canada
437 IBM437  OEM United States
500 IBM500  IBM EBCDIC International
708 ASMO-708    Arabic (ASMO 708)
709     Arabic (ASMO-449+, BCON V4)
710     Arabic - Transparent Arabic
720 DOS-720 Arabic (Transparent ASMO); Arabic (DOS)
737 ibm737  OEM Greek (formerly 437G); Greek (DOS)
775 ibm775  OEM Baltic; Baltic (DOS)
850 ibm850  OEM Multilingual Latin 1; Western European (DOS)
852 ibm852  OEM Latin 2; Central European (DOS)
855 IBM855  OEM Cyrillic (primarily Russian)
857 ibm857  OEM Turkish; Turkish (DOS)
858 IBM00858    OEM Multilingual Latin 1 + Euro symbol
860 IBM860  OEM Portuguese; Portuguese (DOS)
861 ibm861  OEM Icelandic; Icelandic (DOS)
862 DOS-862 OEM Hebrew; Hebrew (DOS)
863 IBM863  OEM French Canadian; French Canadian (DOS)
864 IBM864  OEM Arabic; Arabic (864)
865 IBM865  OEM Nordic; Nordic (DOS)
866 cp866   OEM Russian; Cyrillic (DOS)
869 ibm869  OEM Modern Greek; Greek, Modern (DOS)
870 IBM870  IBM EBCDIC Multilingual/ROECE (Latin 2); IBM EBCDIC Multilingual Latin 2
874 windows-874 ANSI/OEM Thai (ISO 8859-11); Thai (Windows)
875 cp875   IBM EBCDIC Greek Modern
932 shift_jis   ANSI/OEM Japanese; Japanese (Shift-JIS)
936 gb2312  ANSI/OEM Simplified Chinese (PRC, Singapore); Chinese Simplified (GB2312)
949 ks_c_5601-1987  ANSI/OEM Korean (Unified Hangul Code)
950 big5    ANSI/OEM Traditional Chinese (Taiwan; Hong Kong SAR, PRC); Chinese Traditional (Big5)
1026    IBM1026 IBM EBCDIC Turkish (Latin 5)
1047    IBM01047    IBM EBCDIC Latin 1/Open System
1140    IBM01140    IBM EBCDIC US-Canada (037 + Euro symbol); IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada-Euro)
1141    IBM01141    IBM EBCDIC Germany (20273 + Euro symbol); IBM EBCDIC (Germany-Euro)
1142    IBM01142    IBM EBCDIC Denmark-Norway (20277 + Euro symbol); IBM EBCDIC (Denmark-Norway-Euro)
1143    IBM01143    IBM EBCDIC Finland-Sweden (20278 + Euro symbol); IBM EBCDIC (Finland-Sweden-Euro)
1144    IBM01144    IBM EBCDIC Italy (20280 + Euro symbol); IBM EBCDIC (Italy-Euro)
1145    IBM01145    IBM EBCDIC Latin America-Spain (20284 + Euro symbol); IBM EBCDIC (Spain-Euro)
1146    IBM01146    IBM EBCDIC United Kingdom (20285 + Euro symbol); IBM EBCDIC (UK-Euro)
1147    IBM01147    IBM EBCDIC France (20297 + Euro symbol); IBM EBCDIC (France-Euro)
1148    IBM01148    IBM EBCDIC International (500 + Euro symbol); IBM EBCDIC (International-Euro)
1149    IBM01149    IBM EBCDIC Icelandic (20871 + Euro symbol); IBM EBCDIC (Icelandic-Euro)
1200    utf-16  Unicode UTF-16, little endian byte order (BMP of ISO 10646); available only to managed applications
1201    unicodeFFFE Unicode UTF-16, big endian byte order; available only to managed applications
1250    windows-1250    ANSI Central European; Central European (Windows)
1251    windows-1251    ANSI Cyrillic; Cyrillic (Windows)
1252    windows-1252    ANSI Latin 1; Western European (Windows)
1253    windows-1253    ANSI Greek; Greek (Windows)
1254    windows-1254    ANSI Turkish; Turkish (Windows)
1255    windows-1255    ANSI Hebrew; Hebrew (Windows)
1256    windows-1256    ANSI Arabic; Arabic (Windows)
1257    windows-1257    ANSI Baltic; Baltic (Windows)
1258    windows-1258    ANSI/OEM Vietnamese; Vietnamese (Windows)
1361    Johab   Korean (Johab)
10000   macintosh   MAC Roman; Western European (Mac)
10001   x-mac-japanese  Japanese (Mac)
10002   x-mac-chinesetrad   MAC Traditional Chinese (Big5); Chinese Traditional (Mac)
10003   x-mac-korean    Korean (Mac)
10004   x-mac-arabic    Arabic (Mac)
10005   x-mac-hebrew    Hebrew (Mac)
10006   x-mac-greek Greek (Mac)
10007   x-mac-cyrillic  Cyrillic (Mac)
10008   x-mac-chinesesimp   MAC Simplified Chinese (GB 2312); Chinese Simplified (Mac)
10010   x-mac-romanian  Romanian (Mac)
10017   x-mac-ukrainian Ukrainian (Mac)
10021   x-mac-thai  Thai (Mac)
10029   x-mac-ce    MAC Latin 2; Central European (Mac)
10079   x-mac-icelandic Icelandic (Mac)
10081   x-mac-turkish   Turkish (Mac)
10082   x-mac-croatian  Croatian (Mac)
12000   utf-32  Unicode UTF-32, little endian byte order; available only to managed applications
12001   utf-32BE    Unicode UTF-32, big endian byte order; available only to managed applications
20000   x-Chinese_CNS   CNS Taiwan; Chinese Traditional (CNS)
20001   x-cp20001   TCA Taiwan
20002   x_Chinese-Eten  Eten Taiwan; Chinese Traditional (Eten)
20003   x-cp20003   IBM5550 Taiwan
20004   x-cp20004   TeleText Taiwan
20005   x-cp20005   Wang Taiwan
20105   x-IA5   IA5 (IRV International Alphabet No. 5, 7-bit); Western European (IA5)
20106   x-IA5-German    IA5 German (7-bit)
20107   x-IA5-Swedish   IA5 Swedish (7-bit)
20108   x-IA5-Norwegian IA5 Norwegian (7-bit)
20127   us-ascii    US-ASCII (7-bit)
20261   x-cp20261   T.61
20269   x-cp20269   ISO 6937 Non-Spacing Accent
20273   IBM273  IBM EBCDIC Germany
20277   IBM277  IBM EBCDIC Denmark-Norway
20278   IBM278  IBM EBCDIC Finland-Sweden
20280   IBM280  IBM EBCDIC Italy
20284   IBM284  IBM EBCDIC Latin America-Spain
20285   IBM285  IBM EBCDIC United Kingdom
20290   IBM290  IBM EBCDIC Japanese Katakana Extended
20297   IBM297  IBM EBCDIC France
20420   IBM420  IBM EBCDIC Arabic
20423   IBM423  IBM EBCDIC Greek
20424   IBM424  IBM EBCDIC Hebrew
20833   x-EBCDIC-KoreanExtended IBM EBCDIC Korean Extended
20838   IBM-Thai    IBM EBCDIC Thai
20866   koi8-r  Russian (KOI8-R); Cyrillic (KOI8-R)
20871   IBM871  IBM EBCDIC Icelandic
20880   IBM880  IBM EBCDIC Cyrillic Russian
20905   IBM905  IBM EBCDIC Turkish
20924   IBM00924    IBM EBCDIC Latin 1/Open System (1047 + Euro symbol)
20932   EUC-JP  Japanese (JIS 0208-1990 and 0212-1990)
20936   x-cp20936   Simplified Chinese (GB2312); Chinese Simplified (GB2312-80)
20949   x-cp20949   Korean Wansung
21025   cp1025  IBM EBCDIC Cyrillic Serbian-Bulgarian
21027       (deprecated)
21866   koi8-u  Ukrainian (KOI8-U); Cyrillic (KOI8-U)
28591   iso-8859-1  ISO 8859-1 Latin 1; Western European (ISO)
28592   iso-8859-2  ISO 8859-2 Central European; Central European (ISO)
28593   iso-8859-3  ISO 8859-3 Latin 3
28594   iso-8859-4  ISO 8859-4 Baltic
28595   iso-8859-5  ISO 8859-5 Cyrillic
28596   iso-8859-6  ISO 8859-6 Arabic
28597   iso-8859-7  ISO 8859-7 Greek
28598   iso-8859-8  ISO 8859-8 Hebrew; Hebrew (ISO-Visual)
28599   iso-8859-9  ISO 8859-9 Turkish
28603   iso-8859-13 ISO 8859-13 Estonian
28605   iso-8859-15 ISO 8859-15 Latin 9
29001   x-Europa    Europa 3
38598   iso-8859-8-i    ISO 8859-8 Hebrew; Hebrew (ISO-Logical)
50220   iso-2022-jp ISO 2022 Japanese with no halfwidth Katakana; Japanese (JIS)
50221   csISO2022JP ISO 2022 Japanese with halfwidth Katakana; Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana)
50222   iso-2022-jp ISO 2022 Japanese JIS X 0201-1989; Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana - SO/SI)
50225   iso-2022-kr ISO 2022 Korean
50227   x-cp50227   ISO 2022 Simplified Chinese; Chinese Simplified (ISO 2022)
50229       ISO 2022 Traditional Chinese
50930       EBCDIC Japanese (Katakana) Extended
50931       EBCDIC US-Canada and Japanese
50933       EBCDIC Korean Extended and Korean
50935       EBCDIC Simplified Chinese Extended and Simplified Chinese
50936       EBCDIC Simplified Chinese
50937       EBCDIC US-Canada and Traditional Chinese
50939       EBCDIC Japanese (Latin) Extended and Japanese
51932   euc-jp  EUC Japanese
51936   EUC-CN  EUC Simplified Chinese; Chinese Simplified (EUC)
51949   euc-kr  EUC Korean
51950       EUC Traditional Chinese
52936   hz-gb-2312  HZ-GB2312 Simplified Chinese; Chinese Simplified (HZ)
54936   GB18030 Windows XP and later: GB18030 Simplified Chinese (4 byte); Chinese Simplified (GB18030)
57002   x-iscii-de  ISCII Devanagari
57003   x-iscii-be  ISCII Bangla
57004   x-iscii-ta  ISCII Tamil
57005   x-iscii-te  ISCII Telugu
57006   x-iscii-as  ISCII Assamese
57007   x-iscii-or  ISCII Odia
57008   x-iscii-ka  ISCII Kannada
57009   x-iscii-ma  ISCII Malayalam
57010   x-iscii-gu  ISCII Gujarati
57011   x-iscii-pa  ISCII Punjabi
65000   utf-7   Unicode (UTF-7)
65001   utf-8   Unicode (UTF-8)
```

Comment: "ANSI code pages can be different on different computers, or can be changed for a single computer". Например, минимум трёх кодировок, которые есть у меня на компьютере, в этом списке нет. Лучше запрашивать у системы локально.